Imported model has no shading faces only an outline
I imported a glass model and in the viewport I can only see the outline. I can see a wireframe of the mesh only if I enable "Show overlays". Still no faces. I added a cube for reference. Why aren't the imported models shaded?


Are the glasses set to Wire in the Object Properties under Viewport Display > Display As? display as wire

No it is set to texture. But I did import a .max file. I think that is the problem. Still looking for a fix.

The solidify mod doesnt give any results. Copy polygons the same. Normals are ok.

I have no idea what "copy polygons" means in this case. I have thought about backface culling, but when normals are "ok", this should not be the issue either. I guess before we ask for every single possible reason it might be better if you upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Got it to work by importing an obj file.
